# How can i send/receive JSON files through gRPC communications? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, grpc, grpc-node

Analyzing quick guides I was able to understand how to set up the protocol buffers to send/receive objects already known by client and server.

My doubt is how to send or receive an entire JSON file, even when I dont know its properties and types. There's a way to do that?

On the proto3 documentation theres no such type as "JSON".

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "Any" type is what you are looking for. Also look into mapping, and JSON mapping. It is there in the documentation you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The `google.protobuf.Struct` type is the common solution for representing arbitrary JSON structures in Protobuf. It uses a map field to support arbitrary field names, and the `google.protobuf.Value` type uses a `oneof` field to support arbitrary value types, including nested `Struct` values.